# Microsoft edge date input shows value twice

Tags: html, date, microsoft-edge

Environment:

```
EmberJS: 3.16
Typescript
MS Edge
```

As I started testing our app on MS Edge, I noticed that date fields were showing pre-set values twice in the date input field. If I don't pre-set the value of the date, it's fine: it just shows the placeholder once like expected and when selecting the value in the picker, it shows it once like expected. But once I set the value in the rendered HTML, it shows twice. Also, it shows it in two different formats (1 is heiphenated, the other is forward slash).

[image: duplicate date values]

When I change the date value with the picker, the first display stays the same but the second one reflects my selection.

I have some basic styling on the input itself like padding, margin and border but, other than that, I am relying on the default browser implementation of the datepicker.

Here is my html (I'm using Ember and Handlebars so the values I have here are replaced with valid values):

```
<input
  value={{this.goalDueDate}}
  type="date"
  min={{this.minDueDate}}
  max={{this.maxDueDate}} />
```

And the value passed into the input field (`this.goalDueDate`) is set to the following:

```
this.goal.dueDate = "2020-03-18T00:00:00.000-04:00";
this.goalDueDate = moment(this.goal?.dueDate ?? moment()).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
this.minDueDate = moment().add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
this.maxDueDate = "9999-12-31";
```

Comment: From your code, it seems that your application is an Angular application, right? If that is the case, can you tell us the version of Angular? Besides, whether you are using some date picker plugin, or just using the date control's default behavior to select a date, can you explain more detail about it? If you could create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it might be easier for us to reproduce the problem and  narrow down the issue.

Comment: I updated my question. We're using EmberJS and we're relying on the default browser implementation

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, whether you are using some date picker plugin? If you could create a minimal example, it might be easier to narrow down the problem. Besides, as a workaround, I suggest you could try to use the input text element to display the date, instead of using the input date element. Then using a JQuery datepicker plugin to select a date.